# Can I show iAds in my second version?

Tags: ios

I am trying to make my first version of an iOS app. I want to release this version without ads and I want to add them (iAds) in the later versions. Can I do like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can! Adding iAds to version 1.0 is no different from adding it to version 2.0.

Read [Apple's documentations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) on iAds to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can add whatever you like in a future update. Of course the update has to pass the App store check.